# Make a bot search into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that takes over the information from an info.json file and brings it under the form of a rich embed into the Discord Channel.

My problem that I keep having and seems I can't find the solution on my own is that my JSON info file contains a large number of arrays that need to be accessed by using the "prefix + player name" command.

Example of Array in JSON:

```
{
  "playername": "riky",
  "age": 20,
  "height": 172
}
```

So when a person wants to search, for example, `riky` by using the `prefix + riky` command, the bot should bring in front all the info the riky contains: `age`, `height`, etc.

Can anyone help me with something like this?

Comment: It's unclear what the prefix is, can you post the structure of the whole json?

Comment: I am not trying to be rude just helpful, that example is not an Array of JSON, but just JSON. An array doesn't have a key to value relationship it is just a list of things. In JSON an array would look like this `{ "arrayData": ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'something', 'foo', 'bar']}`. In that example, after you parsed the JSON into a Javascript object the key would be `arrayData` and the value would be an Array.

Answer (score 0):

I used fs to get your json file. I do a for loop to go through all your json arrays and search for the playername that you entered in your command. If the bot finds an array with this playername, he assigns the age and the height to a new variable.

After this, you can create your RichEmbed and send it in the channel.

Try to use the following code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const jsonFile = fs.readFile('PATH of your JSON');
const playerName = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1);

let age;
let hight;

for (var i = 0; i < jsonFile.length; i++) {
  if (jsonFile[i].playername === playerName) {
    age = jsonFile[i].age;
    hight = jsonFile[i].hight;
  }
}

if (!age || !height) return message.channel.send('Couldn\'t find this player!');

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle(playername)
  .addField('Age', age)
  .addField('Hight', hight);

message.channel.send({ embed });
```